# Upgrading ColdFusion 10 32 BIT JDK

Tags: coldfusion-10

I have a windows 32 bit version of ColdFusion 10. I would like to get the JDK up to the latest version however I can't seem to find a 32 bit installation at the Oracle site.

Answer (score 2):

It's right there on the download page - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

The files labeled as `...-windows-i586.exe` are the 32-bit installers.

The files labeled as `...-windows-x64.exe` are the 64-bit installers.

And for what it's worth, the following lists the [JDK supported for ColdFusion](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/which-jdk-is-supported-with-coldfusion-9-10-and-11) 10:

> Update 14 and later: JDK 8
>
> Updates 8-13: JDK 7
>
> Update 7 and earlier: JDK 6

Comment: Thanks for listing the JDK support per ColdFusion 10 update.